# How to use openlayers 3 with epsg 32749

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, openlayers

I want to set coordinates of my map in epsg 32749.

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center:ol.proj.transform([43037,9138591],'EPSG:32749','EPSG:900913'),
    zoom:10.8
    });

var map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    view:  view

});
```

and how to use projs4 to my html?

Comment: What is the question? Do you have some problem with proj4js? If so, what is it? What do you want to do in terms of projection? Also, what is the intent of "10.8" as a zoom level?

Comment: I want to openlayers 3 can defined epsg 32749. because I have a coordinate with epsg 32749. so can you explain to me, how it will defined epsg 32749?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I'm still not getting what you are asking. Are you asking about how OpenLayers 3 knows what EPSG:32749 is? Or are you trying to figure out how to show a point?

Comment: asking about how OpenLayers 3 knows what EPSG:32749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the projection 32749. You need proj4.js.

> Download the proj4js zip  from http://proj4js.org/.

Extract the zip file and find proj4.js file from dist folder and add the file to your project. Then you need to define the proj4js definiton for EPSG:32749.

> For that add this javascript file to your application http://epsg.io/32749.js

like this:

```
<script src='http://epsg.io/32749.js'>/<script>
```

for projection variable add like this.

```
var projection = ol.proj.get("EPSG:32749");
```